# counting letters that are not used in a string

Tags: string, if-statement, for-loop

I need help fixing this program where it checks the string for any uppercase letters and if it does to have the user reenter the string until the user only puts lowercase letters.
This is the first part where we check the string for any uppercase letters and asks the user to reenter the string until the string has only lowercase letters I just want to make sure that it is correct. BTW I am only an intro to computer science student so i only know beginner stuff.

```
for (int i=0;i<word.length();i++)
{
    if(word[i]>='a' && word[i]<='z')
    {
        cout<<"Please enter a new string: ";
        cin>>word;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The condition needs to be
if(word[i]<='a' || word[i]>='z')

ASCII of

```
  'A' - 65,
  'Z' - 90,
  'a' - 97,
  'z' - 122
```

Anything that is not in the range [97,122] need to be prompted for a new string

Comment: I did that and it didn't change anything. It still does the same thing when I do a test run on it.

Comment: And even when I put lowercase letters, it still prompts user to enter a new string.

Comment: please remove the equality, it would work. if(word[i]<'a' || word[i]>'z').my mistake

Comment: When i did that it, now it doesn't prompt for a new string even when I put uppercase letters

Comment: It's working. try to assign a flag when you find an Uppercase letter and finally check if the flag is set, if yes , prompt the user for a new string, else not